# Show for $1>a>0$ that $(e^{x}-a)^{-1}\sin(x)$ is integrable over $[0,\infty)$

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

Show  for $1>a>0$ that $(e^{x}-a)^{-1}\sin(x)$ is integrable over $[0,\infty)$

Any help would be super helpful!

Comment: Hint: use boundedness of the sine function.

Comment: How would you then show $(e^x-a)^{-1}$ is integrable? I thought about doing comparison test here and using boundedness of sine but I then hit this road block

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** split up the region of integration as $[0,2]\cup[2,\infty)$. In the first interval, you can trivially bound the function. In the second interval, you can use the boundedness of $\sin(x)$ and bound $e^x-a$ in a nice way.

In this way, you can prove the integral converges absolutely and so it converges.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the bound for $(e^x-a)^{-1}$ , I can’t see how to do this

Comment: At that point, just replace $a$ with $e^x/2$ (this makes the denominator smaller so the fraction gets larger...it also makes the integrand very easy to integrate).

Comment: How can we replace a with e^x/2

Comment: @Sven456 You could also say $\int(e^x-a)^{-1}dx=\frac1a\ln|1-ae^{-x}|+C$.

Comment: @sven: $e^x/2>1>a$ for $x>2$.